# How to fix browser in live server using visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

New to coding and using visual studio code for Mac for the first time as I am following a coding tutorial on freecodecamp.  I installed VSC and live server and Chrome browser extension, yet I get an error when I go to live server:

// = 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf()); } parent.appendChild(elem); } } var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://'; var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws'; var socket = new WebSocket(address); socket.onmessage = function (msg) { if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload(); else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS(); }; if (sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer')) { console.log('Live reload enabled.'); sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true); } })(); } else { console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.'); } // ]]>

I tried on Mozilla, but the extension is not even able to be installed as add on corrupt - https://share.getcloudapp.com/WnuG42w2

Tried without the extension on Firefox and got the same error above as Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I faced the same problem using Visual Code. It is a 'Live Server' error. Live Server tries to inject some code into the original code as a comment, which leads to this error. Refreshing the live server will make things normal again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the tag with a closing tag. For example replace:

```
<textarea
  id="message"
  name="message"
  cols="30"
  rows="10"
/>
```

with:

```
<textarea
  id="message"
  name="message"
  cols="30"
  rows="10"
></textarea>
```

This actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck your codes again. See if there is missing some symbol or tag. In VS Code you understand by the code colors.

I had a similar issue like this. Although, I am new to web development field. The code I was faced problem was:

```
<section>
<div>
  <img src="images/designer.png" alt="web designer>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Big Dream</h1>
  <h2>To become a developer</h2>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>
</section>
```

You see in the `alt=""` part in the `img` tag, I have missed a (`"`) double quotation.